# Ruby change directory in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I've came across an issue where I delete the current folder where my ruby script is executing ex:

```
/home/user/scriptfolder
```

Now i have my ruby gem running and I do this:

```
mycommand --deletefull
```

now mycommand is an GLI command, which should delete the content of the folder and the folder itself. I do that by using my custom class:

```
ClientModuleDir.rm_f(path)
```

now after deleting it I want to just do `cd ..`

however I've tried several methods:

```
system('cd ..')
 Dir.chdir(dir)  #dir is abs path without the scripfolder name, i've tried every combination with this command, nothing works so far.
```

However these methods are not working.

I still am in the

```
/home/user/scriptfolder
```

after executing these commands, but the folder DOES NOT EXIST. When I manually do cd .. and i do ls the folder is not there.

How do I change "physically" the folder in ruby code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current working directory is always kept for the current program only. Changing the working directory in a program won't affect any other running programs, including its parent.

Thus, when you delete the directory in your Ruby script and change the working directory of the Ruby process one level down, this won't affect the shell process which has started your Ruby script.

Comment: Yeah, Figured it out. No way I can make it work in some hacky way?

Comment: No, this is a fundamental feature of how environment variables work across processes (which is what the current directory is). The only way to change the current directory in your shell is by *sourcing* a shell script into the very same process to perform the directory change. It is not enough to run the script in a new process, it must be sourced and executed in the very same shell proces.